# bst insert recursion c++

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have a bst encapsulated in a class with a  nested node.

When I try to insert and then print tree, the root attribute of the class does not seem to be updated,
even though I do update it.

```
void bst::insert(int key,node* temp)
{
  if(temp==NULL)
  {
      node* ptr=getnewnode(key);
      if(root==NULL)
        root=ptr;
       else
       {
         temp=ptr;
         return ;
       }
  }
     if(key<temp->key)
      insert(key,temp->left);
     if(key>temp->key)
      insert(key,temp->right);
}

class bst
{
typedef struct node
{
int key;
node* left;
node* right;
}node;
node* root; 
void insert(int key,node* temp);
public:
inline void _insert(int key){insert(key,root);}   
};
```

When i insert say `22`,`11`,`33` and then print it, it just shows `22`, always the root node.

Comment: The only side effect of your code (besides leaking memory) is changing `root` exactly once, from `NULL` to the return value of the very first `getnewnode` call. Everything else is a very elaborate no-op.

Comment: What effect does `temp=ptr` have before the `return` in that `else` clause?  What type is `node`?

Comment: added the node definition

Comment: temp=ptr, i am assuming means root->right = new node in case of 2nd node addition..root->right comes from the call insert(key,temp->right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that when you call `insert()` from outside the class,  `NULL` is provided as second argument, because `root` is private.

**Problem 1:**

If you `insert(22, NULL)` the first node is added to your bst as foolows:

```
  ... 
     if(root==NULL)   // yes, the bst is still empty:  
        root=ptr;     // so root is set to the new node that was created
     else {...}       // and this bloc is ignored 
  }
  if(key<temp->key)   // OUCH !!!! temp is not initalized here                        
  ...
```

You risk here a memory corruption or a segfault !

**Problem 2:**

If you subsequently `insert(11, NULL)` here is what happens:

```
  ... 
      if(root==NULL)   // No, the bst has already a root  
      else {           // so the else block is executed
          temp = ptr;  // you prepare to do something with temp
          return;      // WHY ??  You end the function an return without having done anything 
  ...
```

**Problem 3:**

Suppose you remove the return statement,  then remember that you just overwrote temp.  The code would continue as follows:

```
 if(key<temp->key)     // this is false, because temp points to the new node, which has the seme key (temp->key==key) !
 if(key>temp->key)     // this is false, for the same reason
```

So none of the recursive insert is done !

**Solution:**

I'd propose you something like this:

```
void bst::insert(int key,node* temp)
{
    if(temp==NULL) {
       if(root==NULL) {
           root=getnewnode(key);
           return; 
       }
       else 
           temp=root;  // we now start browsing the tree with root 
    }
    if(key<temp->key) {
        if (temp->left==NULL) 
           temp->left = getnewnode(key);  
       else insert(key,temp->left);
    }
    else if(key>temp->key) {
        if (temp->right==NULL) 
           temp->right = getnewnode(key);
       else insert(key,temp->right);
    }
    else if (key==temp->key) { 
        // to do:  what happens if key==temp->key 
    }
}
```

It's not clear what is expected when an existing key is inserted again.  Up to you to adapt according to your expectations.

**Edit:  Solution with a wrapper:**

Following your edit about using a wrapper I propose you following variant:

```
void bst::insert(int key,node*& temp)  // attention:  change of signature !!!
{
    if(temp==NULL) {  // either root is null or we have reached a null leave
       temp = getnewnode(key);    // temp is a reference to original root or node pointer.  It can be changed directly with this statement 
       }
    else if(key<temp->key) 
       insert(key,temp->left);
    else if(key>temp->key) 
       insert(key,temp->right);
    else if (key==temp->key) { 
        // to do:  what happens if key==temp->key 
    }
}
```

Comment: second point -- Only teh first time insert(12,null) is called because root is null....then onwards, the call is always insert(xyz,root) and root is non null

Comment: @basav:  I've completed the post with my assumptions.  Outside the `bst`, people cannot provide `root` because it's a private member, so I expected, that `NULL` would be the default value when the function is called from oustide.  If it's not the case and if you have a front-end member function that calls `insert()` by providing it `root`, just let me know and show the corresponding code.

Comment: Yes, I have a wrapper function in public taht calls the private method.I have edited the code now accordingly.

Comment: I recommend you to get rid of the wrapper, add a default parameter to your existing function in the class as follows: `public: void insert(int key,node* temp=NULL);` and use the code above.  From outside you could then call insert(22), without additional code.

Comment: That is a nice alternative, i will try it out.thanks.

Comment: @basav  I've edited, taking your wrapper into account.  It requires however that signature of insert() is changed to pass the pointer by reference.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what I was doing wrong here but now the code works with the below changes.
//wrapper function

```
void insert(int key)
{
   node * temp=_insert(key,root);
   preorder(root);
}

node* bst::insert(int key,node* temp)
{
 if(root==NULL)
  {
      node* ptr=getnewnode(key);
        root=ptr;
        return root;
  }
   if(temp==NULL)
  {
       node* ptr=getnewnode(key);
       return ptr;
  }
     if(key<temp->key)
      temp->left=insert(key,temp->left);
     if(key>temp->key)
      temp->right=insert(key,temp->right);
}
```